# Toy suggestion for dog that tears apart fabric/rope toys

Tags: dogs, health, safety, eating, toys

I have a Rhodesian ridgeback/boxer mix and he loves to tear apart toys. He'll hold the toy in his paws and rip them apart using his front teeth. However, I don't want him eating stuff like rope threads or toy stuffing, but he clearly prefers to tear rather than chew.

Are there toys that allow my dog to tear like this that are safe?

I'm happy to provide more detail. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dried skins (I assume most of them are cow skins) seem to be a good alternative. They start out quite hard and stiff, but get softer when sufficiently drenched in saliva ;-). "Soft" being a relative term here, they are still resilient like leather.

Other alternatives are dried pig ears, dried tendons or other unprocessed, dried animal cutoffs. The skin just tends to be most resilient.

Some dogs are too greedy and try swallowing smaller pieces of dried skin before it was sufficiently softened, which usually ends in retching. Try keeping an eye on your dog when he eats his first skin pieces to make sure he doesn't have an accident...